# Magento 1.9 add coupon code to payment page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, coupon, coupon-codes

I want to add the coupon code to the payment page.

That works perfect, but when a coupon code is applied, it redirects back to the cart.

Is there a way to add the coupon code, without redirect to the cart? So maybe a way to use Ajax in the `coupon.phtml` template or change the redirect to the payment method?

Comment: add code that you tried

Comment: @SohelRana I haven't tried anything, because I am not sure how to rewrite the code. I know the redirect to cart location inside the CartController.php. But the reason I ask the question, is that I need some help to keep the customer in the checkout, also without losing the filled checkout fields.